# netstat reports a pid that tasklist cannot find

Tags: windows-7, networking, cygwin

I was trying out cygwin lighttpd and got the error

> can't bind to port:  80 Address already in use

I used `netstat` to find out which process is using it:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -ao | findstr ":80"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             OAKN00511461A:0        LISTENING       2364
```

But `tasklist` cannot find the process!

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tasklist /fi "PID eq 2364"
INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.
```

I rechecked that netstat continues to report the same process:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -ao | findstr ":80"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             OAKN00511461A:0        LISTENING       2364
```

Any suggestion how I can get details of the process and more importantly, kill it?

**UPDATE**

It turned out to be the previously started `lighttpd` process, but `tasklist` does not seem to report it

Comment: What does `http://127.0.0.1` give you in a browser :)

Comment: It gave 404. A little while after posting the question I realized it was lighttpd itself. But I reverified that tasklist does not list the lighttpd process. Something to check

Comment: does tasklist list processes started by other users?

Comment: I think so...pretty sure I ran tasklist as administrator. Besides, I ran `nc` in my bash window which showed up in tasklist.